# JQuery Get Data From Onther Div to Li

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I want this operations using jQuery.
On image click The item should add to the menu.
Suppose I click on pizza image the it should add new li in ul with name pizza. When I again click on image 1 that pizza should be gone. This is code:

```
<body>
<div class="foodcourt">
    <div class="container">
        <header>
           
        </header>
        <section class="maincircle">

            <ul class="ch-grid">
                <li>
                    <div class="ch-item">
                        <div class="ch-info">
                            <div class="ch-info-front ch-img-1"></div>
                            <div class="ch-info-back">
                                <h3>Pizza</h3>
                                <p>Price: ₹100</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                </section>
        <div class="menucard">
            <ul id="list">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want on that image click the menucard class's li added with pizza. and when i click another time it should removed from li.

Comment: where is the image first?

Comment: image is in div tag. ch-info-front ch-img-1, ch-info-front ch-img-2, ch-info-front ch-img-3, ch-info-front ch-img-4. Like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kVV2v/1/)

Your **HTML**:

```
<div class="foodcourt">
    <div class="container">
        <section class="maincircle">
            <ul class="ch-grid">
                <li>
                    <div class="ch-item">
                        <div class="ch-info">
                            <div class="ch-info-front ch-img-1">
                                <img src="http://www.belfast-takeaways.co.uk/img/pizza.jpg" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="ch-info-back">
                                 <h3>Pizza</h3>

                                <p>Price: ₹100</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <div class="menucard">
            <ul id="list"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Some **jQuery**:

```
$(".ch-img-1").live("click", function () {
    var newLi = $('.ch-info .ch-info-back h3').text();
    if ($("#list li:contains(" + newLi + ")").length) {
        $($("#list li:contains(" + newLi + ")")).remove();
    } else {
        $('.menucard #list').append('<li>' + newLi + '</li>');
    }
});
```

Voila!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you..

http://jsfiddle.net/Praveen16oct90/YwRTU/

Do with Your needful..

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
 var add=true;
  $('.ch-info-back').click(function()
 {

   var text=$(this).find('h3').html();
    if(add)
    {
         $('#list').append('<li>'+text+'</li>');
        add=false;
    }
     else
     {
          $('#list').empty();
          add=true;
     }
 });

});
```